# Examining which files are dirty or buffered in Linux

Tags: linux, files, virtual-memory

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo | grep Dirty
Dirty:              2396 kB
```

How do I view in which files (at least as a mountid:inode pairs) are those 599 dirty pages located?

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo | grep Cached
Cached:          6171156 kB
```

How do I view which files are in cache without `vmtouch`ing the entire filesystem?

Maybe there is some netlink or debugfs or /dev/kmem-reading or whatever trick to do this?

Comment: I doubt they can be monitored as there is absolutely no good reason to do so.  Dirty pages simply mean that they're pending a disk write.  This is done to optimize overall system operations and would be quite unsuccessful if it was monitorable.  It's fairly easy to assume that most dirty pages represent latest writes from your applications.

Comment: "latest writes from your applications" -> that's why I may want to inspect it. Non-intrusive system-wide "what's happening on my system". I expect kernel to already know it, so the problem is only to persuade it to tell.

Comment: @Vi. I expect the kernel readily knows which *blocks* are cached or dirty, but mapping that to *files* may be quite a bit tougher.

Comment: @Celada, As a minimum there should be information which device has dirty pages pending.

Comment: Would flushing the caches and check what is being flushed (like with `blktrace` or `stap`) be an option for you?

Comment: The best I can come up with is to `mmap` every file on the file system and use `mincore`. That would read all metadata on the file system, but it wouldn't have to page in all the file contents.

Comment: While something is traversing the entire filesystem, dirty pages gets written back multiple times. I want the kernel to just tell what is already knows, not try to obtain some new information.

Comment: What about parsing strace with sync ? By the way, if sync force persistent storage writes you should see which block maybe informations to get files ?

Comment: @Leahkim, `strace` is about debugging the boundary between kernel- and userspace. If used on `/usr/bin/sync`, I expect it to show just the `sync(2)` syscall, without details of its processing within the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

You probably could use the [crash-utility](https://github.com/crash-utility/crash).

In particular use the [`files`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/crash.8.html) command

- Together with the `-c` option in order to display detailed information about pages that are in the page cache for each currently open file.
- Together with the `-p` option in order to display all the pages that are in the page cache for a given inode.